# How to store or index geo data?

Tags: mysql, solr, geolocation, indexing, sphinx

I have an issue and don't really know where to start :

- I have user that choose geolocalize data (eg : San Franciso, 50 miles)
- I need to perform search on this (eg : San Jose) and return user that have the city in their perimeter.

I use Sphinx (but change can be an option) and MySQL, I tried to make an multi attribute with all the cities while indexing : it crash my server while indexing.
So I make a cron that store User -> City links in database. It works fine for Sphinx, but my cron is a bit too greedy (and the table grow very fast, an user can have nearly 1000 cities in his perimeter).

Do you know a good solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: It would help to actully add details, of how exactly you are doing this. A copy of your table definition, and a few example rows maybe. This would help others visualize the data you have (its not clear at the moment)

Comment: I have a demo using **PHP/MySQL** to find railway stations in UK using the [Haversine Formula](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) It can be seen                                                   [Here](http://daviestrachan.co.uk/maps/stationmap8a.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible through Sphinx. You need to have `latitude` and `longitude` of each of the cities in database and need to add as attribute in Sphinx.

Sphinx uses a magic function **`@geodist`** for calculation of points of interest (POI) within range.

Need to change Sphinx config file as below:

```
source geolocation
{
    sql_query            = select city_id, radians(longitude) as longitude,   
                           radians(latitude) as latitude from cities 
    sql_attr_float       = longitude
    sql_attr_float       = latitude
}
```

Note that the `sql_query` uses the `radians` function to convert `degrees to radians`. `sql_attr_float` tells Sphinx that the longitude/latitude are floats. THis is needed for the magic `@geodist` function. The `sql_query_info` is handy if you debugging on the command line.

Below is `PHP` code to execute Sphinx Search to retrieve Geo Location search

```
$_longitude = $_GET['longitude'];
$_latitude = $_GET['latitude'];
$_radius = $_GET['radius'];

$search = new SphinxClient();
$search->SetServer("localhost", 3312);
$search->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_ALL);
$search->SetArrayResult(true);
$search->SetLimits(0, 100);
$search->SetGeoAnchor('latitude', 'longitude', (float) deg2rad($_latitude),  
                     (float) deg2rad($_longitude));

$circle = (float) $_radius * 1.61;
$search->SetFilterFloatRange('@geodist', 0.0, $circle);

$result = $search->Query('', 'geolocation');
```

Comment: Hi Minesh, thanks for your answer.

I have seen this, but as my users can choose more than one city I can't use this (it was my first choice), or maybe I don't see how to do... Any idea?

Comment: @EricCambray You might consider radius calculation from Database(MySql) combination and retrieve city_ids and have MVA on city_id in sphinx, then you can apply sphinx filter based on city_id to retrieve the data.

Answer (score 0):

I had a project similar to yours last year and got the same problem. I had to switch to SphinxQL instead of the php API and first worked much faster and you have more options as API give you.